# How to evaluate $\int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z^2+z+1} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I found the poles of $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2+z+1}$ given by the solutions for $z^2 + z + 1$, $ \displaystyle z_1 = -\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\displaystyle z_2 = -\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

But when I use the Residue's Theorem, I get an indetermination. For example, for $z_1$ $$\displaystyle Res\left(\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}, -\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)= \lim_{z \to -\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} \left((z - \left(-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}\right) $$$$= (0)(\frac{1}{0})$$

Is this the way I should treat this problem or should I try with something else?

Comment: Cancel the common factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Just observe that
\begin{align*}
(z - (-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}))(\frac{1}{z^2+z+1})&=(z-z_1)\times\frac 1{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\\
&=\frac 1{z-z_2}\qquad\text{for all }z\neq z_1
\end{align*}
So, the limit you are looking for is
$$\lim_{z\to z_1}\left[(z - z_1)\times\frac{1}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\right]=\lim_{z\to z_1}\frac{1}{z-z_2}=\frac{1}{z_1-z_2}=\frac{1}{i\sqrt 3}=-\frac 1{\sqrt 3}i$$

Comment: So, for $z_2$ the residue should be $+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and it will make my integral equal to $0$ (that's what they gave me as the answer).

Comment: Another question. If I have $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)(z-3i)}$, the best option I have is to solve the integral by partial fractions?

Comment: For this question the answer is zero.

For the second question, yes, you can use partial fractions and then use Residue Theorem. Cauchy's integral formula can also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Factorize: 
$z^2+z+1=\left(z-\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}\right)\left(z-\frac{-1-i\sqrt3}{2}\right)$ 
 $$\text{Re}\left(\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}, \frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}\right)$$$$=\left[\left(z-\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}\right)\frac{1}{\left(z-\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}\right)\left(z-\frac{-1-i\sqrt3}{2}\right)}\right]_{z=\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}}$$
$$=\left[\frac{1}{\left(z-\frac{-1-i\sqrt3}{2}\right)}\right]_{z=\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}}$$
Similarly,
$$\text{Re}\left(\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}, \frac{-1-i\sqrt3}{2}\right)=\left[\frac{1}{\left(z-\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}\right)}\right]_{z=\dfrac{-1-i\sqrt3}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$z^2+z+1=\left (z- \left(-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right )\left(z-\left(  -\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)$$